# jQuery outerHeight() returns 0 even with jQuery(window).load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, outerheight

After i loaded content with ajax i wanna get the outerHeight of the loaded elements.

Ajaxload file:

```
$('#workshop').submit(function(event){



        $.ajax({
        url: URL,
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#workshop').serialize(),
        success: function(data){

            var string = '<div class="section" id="result"></div>';

            if(prevent == true){
                 $('#container #result').html($("#main .inside>.mod_article", data));

                 $.getScript( scriptURL, function() {
                        });
            }else{
                $('#container').append(string);
                $('#container #result').html($("#main .inside>.mod_article", data));


                    $.getScript( scriptURL, function() {
                        });


                prevent = true;

            }

    });
        event.preventDefault();
});
```

The script loaded looks like :

```
var height;
var top ;

function scroll_down(){

jQuery(window).load(function(){
    $('.result_control .up').css({'display' : 'block'});

    top = $('.item_wrapper>.inner').css('top');
     height =  $('.item_wrapper>.inner>.item').outerHeight(true);

});

console.log(top);
console.log(height);

}


function scroll_up(){
console.log('up');
}

$('.item_wrapper').mousewheel(function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY){
if(delta > 0){
    scroll_up();
}else if(delta < 0){
    scroll_down();
}
 });
```

The HTML of the loaded elements :

```
<div class="item_wrapper">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The css code of these elements :

```
.section#result .workshopfilter .filterresult .item_wrapper {
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
height: 65%;
position: relative;
clear: both !important;
}
.section#result .workshopfilter .filterresult .inner {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
clear: both !important;
 }
.section#result .workshopfilter .filterresult div.item {
float: left;
margin-right: 1%;
margin-left: 1%;
margin-bottom: 2%; 
width: 27%;
background-color: #ffff00;
color: #333;
height: 250px;
padding: 2%;
position: relative;
display: block;
font-family:'AmericanTypwrterITCW01- 731031';
}
```

.css() returns  object

.outerHeight returns 0

The elements are visible and displayed:block.
I dont know how to fix it to get the right properties.

Comment: Can you give us an html sample containing the .item_wrapper container.

Comment: Have you confirmed that your `$('.item_wrapper>.inner>.item')` code actually selects an element?

Comment: @OlivierH I edited my question, see the html code above.

Comment: @RichPeck If i do console.log() on this it will returns all div.item
 i also tried it with .first() because there are multiple matched elements on the "$('.item_wrapper>.inner>.item')" selector

Comment: What is returned if you type directly $('.item_wrapper>.inner>.item').outerHeight(true);
into your browser's javascript console ? Of course after the submit of your #workshop form

Comment: So you're calling the `.item` elements -- do you want to load all of their heights, or just the first one? From my understanding, outerheight only works for one element, so you might just want to run it on the containing DIV?

Comment: @OlivierH In the console it returns 0

Comment: @RichPeck i want the outerHeight of one item to work with that property. outerHeight only works for one element but outerHeight returns the property of the first matched element.
Otherwise i also tryed to specify it with .first()

Comment: I'm trying to understand how your outerHeight is going to work -- you only want to select the first element? What's the reason for selecting the element? I think your problem is systemic (it's related to how your function works, rather than the .outerHeight not working)

Comment: @RichPeck All items got the same height so it isnt't relevant which item will return the value.
I developing a function where the .inner will change the "top" property onclick or onscroll but i need to know when the last items are displayed therefore i need calcalute it depending on the outerheight property. The problem is i need to do it with outerHeight because the site is responsive so i need variable values.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your information. Let me think about it a bit more :)

Comment: @RichPeck thank you for your help.
Looking forward to your answer :)

Comment: @RichPeck if i specify it with .first() it returns a function

Comment: try it : 
$('.item_wrapper>.inner>.item').each(function(){
   console.log($(this).outerHeight());
});

Comment: @OlivierH returns 30times "0" and 30times "297".
But there are only 30 times div.item
The number of div.item is depending on the result of the form.

Comment: Now i got the right value with using : $('.item_wrapper>.inner>.item').each(function(){
    if($(this).outerHeight(true) != "" && $(this).outerHeight(true) != 0 ){
     height = $(this).outerHeight(true);
    } 
  });

Comment: What Oliver & I are suggesting, I think, is that `.outerHeight` is not being used correctly. As demonstrated by your recent test, it *is* bringing back correct numbers.... but you want to take the first element's height & multiply by 30 to get the total items height?

Answer (score 0):

since ajax is async. you need to specify the variables inside the callback function of `load
()` which in you case is outside

```
 jQuery(window).load(function(){
    $('.result_control .up').css({'display' : 'block'});
    top = $('.item_wrapper>.inner').css('top');
    height =  $('.item_wrapper>.inner>.item').outerHeight;

    console.log(top);  //here
    console.log(height); //here

});
```

since you have your console.log outside the load callback function.. console.log is called before the `load` completes hence giving you nothing

Comment: That didn't fix my problem, still returns 0 I think the problem isn't caused by that the elements aren't loaded when i request the outerHeight of the elements. I was reading alot of possible fixes for equaly problems , but nothing works.